# Would like to adjust the shape of the graph and positioning when copying and pasting from excel to powerpoint

Tags: excel, vba

I am copying and pasting graphs from excel to powerpoint through a macro in VBA, however I'm not sure what the syntax for adjusting the shape and positioning the graphs in powerpoint is. I want to move the graph into the middle of the page and i need the shape smaller than what its pasted as.

The code im using is:

```html
Sub CreatePowerPoint()

 'Add a reference to the Microsoft PowerPoint Library by:
    '1. Go to Tools in the VBA menu
    '2. Click on Reference
    '3. Scroll down to Microsoft PowerPoint X.0 Object Library, check the box, and press Okay
 
    'First we declare the variables we will be using
        Dim newPowerPoint As PowerPoint.Application
        Dim activeSlide As PowerPoint.slide
        Dim cht As Excel.ChartObject
     
     'Look for existing instance
        On Error Resume Next
        Set newPowerPoint = GetObject(, "PowerPoint.Application")
        On Error GoTo 0
     
    'Let's create a new PowerPoint
        If newPowerPoint Is Nothing Then
            Set newPowerPoint = New PowerPoint.Application
        End If
    'Make a presentation in PowerPoint
        If newPowerPoint.Presentations.Count = 0 Then
            newPowerPoint.Presentations.Add
        End If
     
    'Show the PowerPoint
        newPowerPoint.Visible = True
    
    'Loop through each chart in the Excel worksheet and paste them into the PowerPoint
        For Each cht In ActiveSheet.ChartObjects
        
        'Add a new slide where we will paste the chart
            newPowerPoint.ActivePresentation.Slides.Add newPowerPoint.ActivePresentation.Slides.Count + 1, ppLayoutText
            newPowerPoint.ActiveWindow.View.GotoSlide newPowerPoint.ActivePresentation.Slides.Count
            Set activeSlide = newPowerPoint.ActivePresentation.Slides(newPowerPoint.ActivePresentation.Slides.Count)
                
        'Copy the chart and paste it into the PowerPoint as a Metafile Picture
            cht.Select
            ActiveChart.ChartArea.Copy
            activeSlide.Shapes.PasteSpecial(DataType:=ppPasteMetafilePicture).Select
            
    '   'Set the title of the slide the same as the title of the chart
            activeSlide.Shapes(1).TextFrame.TextRange.Text = cht.Chart.ChartTitle.Text
        
            
        'Adjust the positioning of the Chart on Powerpoint Slide
            newPowerPoint.ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange.Left = 15
            newPowerPoint.ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange.Top = 125
        
            activeSlide.Shapes(2).Width = 200
            activeSlide.Shapes(2).Left = 505
            
        Next
     
    AppActivate ("Microsoft PowerPoint")
    Set activeSlide = Nothing
    Set newPowerPoint = Nothing
     
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here we go, this should get you going. I've commented with "-CHANGES MADE" where I've made some changes. You can adjust the size in the code, and it will automatically centre.

```
Sub CreatePowerPoint()

'Add a reference to the Microsoft PowerPoint Library by:
'1. Go to Tools in the VBA menu
'2. Click on Reference
'3. Scroll down to Microsoft PowerPoint X.0 Object Library, check the box, and press Okay

'First we declare the variables we will be using
    Dim newPowerPoint As PowerPoint.Application
    Dim activeSlide As PowerPoint.slide
    Dim cht As Excel.ChartObject

 'Look for existing instance
    On Error Resume Next
    Set newPowerPoint = GetObject(, "PowerPoint.Application")
    On Error GoTo 0

'Let's create a new PowerPoint
    If newPowerPoint Is Nothing Then
        Set newPowerPoint = New PowerPoint.Application
    End If
'Make a presentation in PowerPoint
    If newPowerPoint.Presentations.Count = 0 Then
        newPowerPoint.Presentations.Add
    End If

'Show the PowerPoint
    newPowerPoint.Visible = True

'Loop through each chart in the Excel worksheet and paste them into the PowerPoint
    For Each cht In ActiveSheet.ChartObjects

    'Add a new slide where we will paste the chart
        newPowerPoint.ActivePresentation.Slides.Add newPowerPoint.ActivePresentation.Slides.Count + 1, ppLayoutText
        newPowerPoint.ActiveWindow.View.GotoSlide newPowerPoint.ActivePresentation.Slides.Count
        Set activeSlide = newPowerPoint.ActivePresentation.Slides(newPowerPoint.ActivePresentation.Slides.Count)

    'Copy the chart and paste it into the PowerPoint as a Metafile Picture -CHANGES MADE
        cht.Select
        ActiveChart.ChartArea.Copy

    'CHANGES MADE
        Dim obj As Object
        Set obj = activeSlide.Shapes.Paste

   'Set the title of the slide the same as the title of the chart
        activeSlide.Shapes(1).TextFrame.TextRange.Text = cht.Chart.ChartTitle.Text

    'Adjust the positioning of the Chart on Powerpoint Slide -CHANGES MADE
        obj.Width = 500 'Adjust width and height here
        obj.Height = 300
        With newPowerPoint.ActiveWindow.Presentation.PageSetup
            obj.Left = (.SlideWidth \ 2) - (obj.Width \ 2)
            obj.Top = (.SlideHeight \ 2) - (obj.Height \ 2)
        End With

    Next

AppActivate ("Microsoft PowerPoint")
Set activeSlide = Nothing
Set newPowerPoint = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: you sir. are a legend.